# I try to deploy an app using R Shiny, but the web page immediately quits and says diagnostic information was logged to my JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, r, rstudio, shiny

When I run deployApp() in my R console, it runs and states "Application successfully deployed to http://mockproject.shinyapps.io/Mock". However, when I go to the actual web page an error appears saying

"The application unexpectedly exited.

Diagnostic information has been dumped to the JavaScript error console."

I'm confused as to what to do as I haven't been using JavaScript and don't even know where this Javascript error console is.

Comment: Shiny uses javascript. Does the app run locally? To see the console do this in chrome or firefox: right-click --> inspect element --> console.

Answer (score 4):

In chrome, you can press F12 and then the console button on the far right of the ribbon